# Check my emails?

Tags: .net, email, system.net.mail

Sending emails in .NET is simple - create MailMessage and send using SmtpClient. But how do I check my Inbox i.e. get list of emails that have arrived to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that implements POP or IMAP protocols in the .NET base class library, so you will need to use a third-party library (unless you want to implement them yourself). This SO question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606/free-pop3-net-library